# How to extract more than one column from excel using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

All,

I have the code below to extract one column from XLS.  Now I need to extract two columns.  In this case I need column D and E.  I am not able to figure it out, help is appreciated.  Thank You!

```
$SMTPApprovedXLS = "c:\temp\SMTP\SMTPAPPLIST.XLS"
$SheetName = "Active"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $False
$Workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.open($SMTPApprovedXLS)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.sheets.item($SheetName)
$startRow = 4

$ApprovedIPs = @()

$count = $Worksheet.Cells.Item(65536,4).End(-4162)

for($startRow=4; $startRow -le $count.row; $startRow++)
{
 $ApprovedIPs += $Worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow, 4).Value()
}

$ApprovedIPs | Out-File C:\ApprovedIPs.txt
```

Comment: What's the problem? You don't know how to access `E` or you don't know how to join its contents to that of `D`?

Comment: I guess both, I need to access E and I need the output to have the contents of D and E per row.

Comment: You guess? Well you already have `D`, correct? `$Worksheet.Cells.Item(x,y)` should give you a clue how to access `E`

Comment: I am able to access E by changing X and Y above but I still don't know how to get both per row.  Would you be able to provide a bit more information?